# Linking CSS file with HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML which will refer a CSS file for style. But it looks like HTML file is not able to find the CSS file. I tried with a simple background colour and that also doesn't seem to work.

**VOD.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>All</b></td>
{% for item in VOD1 %}
<td>ID: {{ item[0] }} <br/> Title: {{ item[1] }}<br/>
<img src="{{ item[2] }}" alt="dummy.jpg"> </img>
</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Catch Up</b></td>
{% for item in VOD2 %}
<td>ID: {{ item[0] }} <br/> Title: {{ item[1] }}<br/>
<img src="{{ item[2] }}" alt="dummy.jpg"> </img>
</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS file is as follows.

**mystyle.css**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background-color: black;
}
.myStyle{
height: 50px;
width:50px;
}

td{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

h1 {
color: maroon;
margin-left: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
```

Can some one help me in this? I don't have much experience in this HTML and CSS files.

Comment: Your CSS should not contain `<!DOCTYPE html>` or any html tags, it should just be `body {}...`

Comment: Don't forget to self-close your meta tag. `<meta charset="UTF-8">
` should become `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`

Comment: You can not use html tags in css files. Only use css 

`body {
background-color: black;
}
.myStyle{
height: 50px;
width:50px;
}`

Comment: @SantoshSingh — No, it shouldn't. The `/` serves no purpose except to make people and syntax highlighters that are addicted to XML feel better.

Answer (score 5):

Your CSS file should contain CSS, just CSS, nothing but CSS. It should not be an HTML document.

Remove everything except:

```
body {
background-color: black;
}
.myStyle{
height: 50px;
width:50px;
}

td{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

h1 {
color: maroon;
margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Actually I didn't use those HTML tags. I referred one web site http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-color and changed the code. Even with the one you attached also, I am not able to see the background color changed.

Comment: @Roshanr — There is nothing else obviously wrong with the code you've provided. If it isn't due to you stuffing HTML into a CSS file, then you probably just put the wrong URL in the `href` of the `<link>`.

Comment: Guys.. It worked now. HTML file and CSS was in the same folder. But as Luca mentioned, when i clicked on the link, browser was searching for a CSS file just a level above. Replacing the CSS file above one level solved the problem. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put the follwoing rows in CSS file, this is HTML (not css language).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
```

So **mystyle.css** becomes

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.myStyle{
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
}

td{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

h1 {
  color: maroon;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Actually I didn't use those HTML tags. I referred one web site http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_ . Even without those tags also, I can't its working.

Comment: Are you sure that .html and .css files are in the same folder? Now it seems a problem of bad url. Try to open Source code windows pressing CTRL+U shortcut, find html row that call .css file and you should see this file like a link. Try to click on it. In this way you can know if browser find .css file or not (in this case, path is incorrect)

Comment: @Roshanr Also, when you use <style> it means that css is for THAT page only. Don't forget to make the file extension .css, and make sure your `<link href="">` is pointed to the correct file.

Comment: @Luca.. I can see that clicking on the link from source code does not load the css file. Yes, both are in the same folder.

Comment: @k97513.. Yes, the extension is css and its referring to the correct file. I am sure the HTML is not able to find the CSS but I am not sure why.

Comment: Could you post a link to wherever you have it?

Comment: Guys.. It worked now. HTML file and CSS was in the same folder. But as Luca mentioned, when i clicked on the link, browser was searching for a CSS file just a level above. Replacing the CSS file above one level solved the problem. Thanks Luca for debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

A css file is a special type of file that can be used as a sort of "insert" for html. Because it's not a .html file, it doesn't need html tags, and html tags will in fact make the file not work. Instead, just put

```
body {
background-color: black;
}
.myStyle{
height: 50px;
width:50px;
}

td{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

h1 {
color: maroon;
margin-left: 40px;
}
```

etc. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp